# RetryOperations is it required?

Tags: spring-retry

Does RetryOperations required when I use retry-spring ?
or is it enough to have the annotation over my method?

```
@Retryable(value = {SQLException.class, Exception.class,RuntimeException.class, RetryException.class, ExhaustedRetryException.class}, //retry will be attempted only if the method throws an SQLException.
        maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff (5000))
public boolean sendJmsMessage(final String xml) {
jmsTemplate.send.........()
// logic to send jms

}


@Recover
  public void ExhaustedRetryException(ExhaustedRetryException re) {
    LOG.error("Failed to deliver the message using the retry");
 }
```

Comment: `@Retryable` should be enough. But where is the method you wanna retry? Or what is the real problem you faced?

Comment: I just did some , sorry

Comment: It's sending jms message in active mq

Comment: what's the use of RetryOperations cases?

Comment: I think you have a XY problem. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: in your example, the retry mechanism should work, without `RetryOperations`. If it's not working maybe you have a configuration problem. Do you have a class annotated with `@Configuration` and `@EnableRetry`, something like `@Configuration @EnableRetry public class AppConfig { ... }`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176255/discussion-between-jorj-and-samarland).

Comment: I was asking about the RetryOperations is required or not : ) so I think I got the answer , Thanks!